# Magnolia Blossom module can't find .jsp templates

Tags: java, jsp, content-management-system, magnolia

I'm trying to create some simple template using magnolia blossom module. The problem occurs when I'm trying to display site, it says that it can't  render template (.jsp file not found).

**Project Structure**

[image: Project Structure]

**MainTemplate.java**

```
@Template(id = "websiteModule:pages/mainTemplate", title = "Main Template")
@TemplateDescription("Main Template example with Blossom")
@Controller
public class MainTemplate {

  @RequestMapping("/mainTemplate")
  public String render() {
    return "pages/mainTemplate.jsp";
  }

  @TabFactory("Site Settings")
  public void homeDialog(UiConfig cfg, TabBuilder tab) {

    tab.fields(
        cfg.fields.text("title").label("Title").description("The HTML page title"),
        cfg.fields.text("metaDescription").label("Meta Description").description("HTML Meta Description of the web site"),
        cfg.fields.text("metaKeywords").label("Meta Keywords").description("HTML Meta Keywords of the web site")
    );
  }
}
```

**blossom-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <context:annotation-config/>

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.brightit" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="info.magnolia.module.blossom.annotation.Template"/>
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="info.magnolia.module.blossom.annotation.Area"/>
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="info.magnolia.module.blossom.annotation.DialogFactory"/>
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="info.magnolia.module.blossom.annotation.VirtualURIMapper"/>
    <context:include-filter type="assignable" expression="info.magnolia.cms.beans.config.VirtualURIMapping"/>
  </context:component-scan>

  <bean class="info.magnolia.module.blossom.web.BlossomRequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="customArgumentResolvers">
      <list>
        <bean class="info.magnolia.module.blossom.web.BlossomHandlerMethodArgumentResolver" />
      </list>
    </property>
    <!-- For @Valid - JSR-303 Bean Validation API -->
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
        <property name="validator">
          <bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="redirectPatterns">
      <list>
        <value>website:*</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean class="info.magnolia.module.blossom.preexecution.BlossomHandlerMapping">
    <property name="targetHandlerMappings">
      <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
          <property name="useSuffixPatternMatch" value="false" />
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />

  <bean class="info.magnolia.module.blossom.view.UuidRedirectViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
  </bean>

  <!-- JSP - renders all views that end with .jsp -->
  <bean class="info.magnolia.module.blossom.view.TemplateViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="2"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/templates/websiteModule/"/>
    <property name="viewNames" value="*.jsp"/>
    <property name="viewRenderer">
      <bean class="info.magnolia.module.blossom.view.JspTemplateViewRenderer">
        <property name="contextAttributes">
          <map>
            <entry key="damfn">
              <bean class="info.magnolia.rendering.renderer.ContextAttributeConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="damfn"/>
                <property name="componentClass" value="info.magnolia.dam.templating.functions.DamTemplatingFunctions"/>
              </bean>
            </entry>
          </map>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <!-- Freemarker - renders all views that end with .ftl -->
  <bean class="info.magnolia.module.blossom.view.TemplateViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="3"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/websiteModule/"/>
    <property name="viewNames" value="*.ftl"/>
    <property name="viewRenderer">
      <bean class="info.magnolia.module.blossom.view.FreemarkerTemplateViewRenderer">
        <property name="contextAttributes">
          <map>
            <entry key="cms">
              <bean class="info.magnolia.rendering.renderer.ContextAttributeConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="cms"/>
                <property name="componentClass" value="info.magnolia.templating.freemarker.Directives"/>
              </bean>
            </entry>
            <entry key="cmsfn">
              <bean class="info.magnolia.rendering.renderer.ContextAttributeConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="cmsfn"/>
                <property name="componentClass" value="info.magnolia.templating.functions.TemplatingFunctions"/>
              </bean>
            </entry>
            <entry key="stkfn">
              <bean class="info.magnolia.rendering.renderer.ContextAttributeConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="stkfn"/>
                <property name="componentClass" value="info.magnolia.module.templatingkit.functions.STKTemplatingFunctions"/>
              </bean>
            </entry>
            <!-- If you need the DAM templating functions in Freemarker uncomment this block to have them set as an attribute named 'damfn'.
            -->
            <entry key="damfn">
              <bean class="info.magnolia.rendering.renderer.ContextAttributeConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="damfn"/>
                <property name="componentClass" value="info.magnolia.dam.templating.functions.DamTemplatingFunctions"/>
              </bean>
            </entry>
          </map>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

**Exception**

```
2015-03-29 13:04:01,494 ERROR rendering.engine.ModeDependentRenderExceptionHandler: Error while rendering [/brightit-website] with template [websiteModule:pages/mainTemplate] for URI [/brightit-website.html=mgnlPreview=false&mgnlChannel=desktop]:
RenderException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is info.magnolia.rendering.engine.RenderException: Can't render template /templates/websiteModule/pages/mainTemplate.jsp
info.magnolia.rendering.engine.RenderException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is info.magnolia.rendering.engine.RenderException: Can't render template /templates/websiteModule/pages/mainTemplate.jsp
  at info.magnolia.module.blossom.render.BlossomTemplateRenderer.render(BlossomTemplateRenderer.java:86)
  at info.magnolia.rendering.engine.DefaultRenderingEngine.render(DefaultRenderingEngine.java:106)
  at info.magnolia.rendering.engine.DefaultRenderingEngine$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f67b9c97.render(<generated>)
  at info.magnolia.rendering.engine.RenderingFilter.render(RenderingFilter.java:204)
  at info.magnolia.rendering.engine.RenderingFilter.handleTemplateRequest(RenderingFilter.java:139)
  at info.magnolia.rendering.engine.RenderingFilter.doFilter(RenderingFilter.java:91)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:89)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.module.blossom.preexecution.BlossomFilter.doFilter(BlossomFilter.java:82)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:58)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.rendering.model.ModelExecutionFilter.doFilter(ModelExecutionFilter.java:101)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:58)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AggregatorFilter.doFilter(AggregatorFilter.java:103)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:89)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.cms.security.BaseSecurityFilter.doFilter(BaseSecurityFilter.java:57)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:89)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.RepositoryMappingFilter.doFilter(RepositoryMappingFilter.java:108)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:89)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:65)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:89)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:74)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:65)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:89)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.VirtualUriFilter.doFilter(VirtualUriFilter.java:68)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:89)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.module.cache.executor.Bypass.processCacheRequest(Bypass.java:58)
  at info.magnolia.module.cache.executor.CompositeExecutor.processCacheRequest(CompositeExecutor.java:66)
  at info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:153)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:58)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.cms.i18n.I18nContentSupportFilter.doFilter(I18nContentSupportFilter.java:73)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:89)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.RangeSupportFilter.doFilter(RangeSupportFilter.java:84)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:89)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.cms.security.BaseSecurityFilter.doFilter(BaseSecurityFilter.java:57)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:89)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
  at info.magnolia.cms.security.SecurityCallbackFilter.doFilter(SecurityCallbackFilter.java:83)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:58)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.cms.security.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:94)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:58)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.module.templatingkit.filters.SiteMergeFilter.doFilter(SiteMergeFilter.java:112)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:89)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MultiChannelFilter.doFilter(MultiChannelFilter.java:82)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:58)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.GZipFilter.doFilter(GZipFilter.java:73)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:58)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
  at info.magnolia.cms.security.auth.login.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:120)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:89)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:82)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CosMultipartRequestFilter.doFilter(CosMultipartRequestFilter.java:89)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:58)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.module.devicedetection.filter.DeviceDetectionFilter.doFilter(DeviceDetectionFilter.java:71)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:58)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContentTypeFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeFilter.java:112)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:89)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:129)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:89)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:65)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:89)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.doFilter(SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.java:106)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterDispatcher.doDispatch(MgnlFilterDispatcher.java:66)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:107)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:93)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is info.magnolia.rendering.engine.RenderException: Can't render template /templates/websiteModule/pages/mainTemplate.jsp
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:965)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
  at info.magnolia.module.blossom.render.BlossomDispatcherServlet.forward(BlossomDispatcherServlet.java:132)
  at info.magnolia.module.blossom.render.BlossomTemplateRenderer.render(BlossomTemplateRenderer.java:78)
  ... 113 more
Caused by: info.magnolia.rendering.engine.RenderException: Can't render template /templates/websiteModule/pages/mainTemplate.jsp
  at info.magnolia.rendering.renderer.JspRenderer.onRender(JspRenderer.java:80)
  at info.magnolia.module.blossom.view.JspTemplateViewRenderer.onRender(JspTemplateViewRenderer.java:95)
  at info.magnolia.rendering.renderer.AbstractRenderer.render(AbstractRenderer.java:151)
  at info.magnolia.module.blossom.view.TemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(TemplateView.java:74)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
  ... 118 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: File &quot;/templates/websiteModule/pages/mainTemplate.jsp&quot; not found
  at info.magnolia.context.WebContextImpl.include(WebContextImpl.java:197)
  at info.magnolia.rendering.renderer.JspRenderer.onRender(JspRenderer.java:74)
  ... 127 more
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: File &quot;/templates/websiteModule/pages/mainTemplate.jsp&quot; not found
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.handleMissingResource(JspServlet.java:417)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:384)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterDispatcher.doDispatch(MgnlFilterDispatcher.java:74)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:107)
  at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:93)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
  at info.magnolia.module.blossom.support.ForwardRequestWrapper$1.include(ForwardRequestWrapper.java:192)
  at info.magnolia.context.WebContextImpl.include(WebContextImpl.java:194)
  ... 128 more
```

If I'm using FreeMaker(.ftl) instead of .jsp everything works fine. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look where are those jsps extracted in the file system when module is installed. My guess would be the one you are looking for gets extracted to `/templates/websiteModule/pages/mainTemplate.jsp` so using that path you should be able to find it.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: .jsps are extracted to the /WEB-INF/classes/mgnl-files/templates/websiteModule/pages/*.jsp  and If I set this path in the blossom-servlet.xml it works, but all documentation, tutorials etc. says that It should be /templates/websiteModule/. I don't know why I have to add classpath before jsps path to make it works and why in .ftl I don't have to?

Comment: That is not correct. That might be where they are resolved to by your IDE working with the app server, but when you install the module, magnolia will extract those files directly in the webapp. Try to go to Configuration and delete /modules/<yourmodule> node there to force reinstallation and then restart (and of course before you do any of this, make a backup of your environment).

Comment: You are right. It was caused by my setup module class.  I have changed my extracting task and it works like a charm. Thank you very much!